# Apache password Authentication does not work

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, password

I use Apache 2.4.27 on a win10 machine. I followed all the steps found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html).

I added just a single user ("dennis") that can access a folder with username/password. It worked fine, and the first time I tried to access this folder, it asked me for a username/password and never asked me again.

Then I tried to add another user to the same folder, to access it with username/password.

I created a file named "GroupName" (no extension), with this inside : `GroupName: dennis ninja`

I went to my cmd and added a password for ninja with `C:\Apache24\bin>htpasswd C:\Apache24\psw\passwords ninja`

Then I went to httpd.conf and , at the bottom I added

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/safe">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "By Invitation Only"
 #(Following line optional)
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthUserFile "c:/Apache24/psw/passwords"
 AuthGroupFile "c:/Apache24/psw/GroupName"
 Require group GroupName
</Directory>
```

I restarted Apache and I get no errors. But when I go to `http://localhost/safe/safe.html` I still can see the page. Why it doesnt ask me for a password again, since I added another user? Is there a way to "logout" as `dennis`, so it can ask me for password and I can give ninja's password? Or did I made a mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to login in Private browsing mode?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev Yes it asks for a password each time, so I guess I have no errors. But why it doesnt ask for password in "normal" mode? Is there a way to "logout" as one user and give the password of the other? Thanks again Alexander

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication), there's best answer for your question. Here [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957822/how-to-clear-basic-authentication-details-in-chrome), how to clear cache for basic auth in Chrome.